# If an association rule has 90% support, how many transactions contain all the items in A?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, data-mining, association-rules

An association rule has the form $A\Rightarrow C$, where $A$ is the antecedent and $C$ is the consequent. Suppose you have a database of one million transactions.

The questions are:

1. If an association rule has 90% support, how many transactions contain all the items in $A$?
2. For the same rule, how many transactions contain all the items in $C$?
3. For the same rule, how many transactions contain all the items in both $A$ and $C$?

I am studying association rule learning and I couldn't answer the question.
I think the question doesn't provide enough data to solve the questions. Because as far as I know: 
$$
\text{Support}(A \Rightarrow C) = P(A \cup C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A \cap C)
$$
Therefore to find $A$ I need to know $P(C)$ and $(A \cap C)$. And same for the others.

So how can I find the answer to my questions?

Comment: My apologies, @yns, I couldn't figure out how $\ge$ made any sense; I just wasn't thinking. Let me know if anything else is off. Note that there is information about the markup / formatting options CV supports [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Notably, CV supports $\LaTeX$ via mathjax; documentation can be found [here](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm).

Comment: @gung thanks for the information about formatting and also for the editing.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** I don't know much about association rule mining.

That being said from the definitions you've given you can't know the answers to questions 1, 2, or 3 from the given information. To see this simply note that you can have
$$
P(A \cup C) = 0.9
$$
for all $P(A), P(C), P(A \cap C) \in [0,1]$ such that 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(A) + P(C) - P(A \cap C) &= 0.9 &\text{with}\\
P(A), P(C) &\ge P(A \cap C),
\end{align*}
$$
for which you can find infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score -3):

So, are you taking the test tomorrow?

The answer is: 1. Don't know 2. Don't know 3. 90%

Given that in this case U is not the same as in set theory. Here it means cases where both X and Y occur.

Comment: Hi Juan, welcome to the site! As this question has the "self-study" tag, it would be helpful for the OP if you'd edit your answer and provided more details and information about the solutions. Otherwise, I don't see how your answer has any pedagogical value.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that, I'll change it. Thanks

Comment: If $X \cup Y$ means both $X$ and $Y$ occur, then what does $X \cap Y$ mean?

Comment: what this means is, support for Y when X happened, so they both have to occur at the same time, right?

Comment: I mean, from set theory, that sounds like union to you? Or like intersection?

Comment: When both happen it is in the intersection $\cap$, when either happens it is in the union $\cup$. Based on the formula given in the question the support is defined as the union.